# How to enable c++20 in Visual Studio 2019 (16.3 preview 4)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20

How to enable c++20 in Visual Studio 2019 (16.3 preview 4)?
I'm interested in testing some C++20 features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++20 isn't a standard yet. You can chose to enable the latest supported features from the working draft in Visual Studio, however this is obviously neither complete nor guaranteed to be in any way stable:

Right click your project -> Properties -> General -> C++ Language Standard: Select "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest)"