# In C++ is there any way to optimize for empty types for composition as opposed to inheritance?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

A cool feature in C++ is empty base/type optimization, so:

```
struct EmptyType {};

struct Foo : EmptyType
{
    long long a;
};

int main()
{
    sizeof(EmptyType); // Is 1
    sizeof(Foo::a); // Is 8
    sizeof(Foo); // Is not sizeof(a) + sizeof(EmptyType), is still 8
}
```

However I was wondering if you can get this kind of optimization for using empty types in composition:

```
struct EmptyType {};

struct Foo : EmptyType
{
    long long a;
    EmptyType b;
};

int main()
{
    sizeof(EmptyType); // Is 1
    sizeof(Foo::a); // Is 8
    sizeof(Foo); /* Is 16, EmptyType still has to take up its size (ie., 1) in 
                 class Foo. Of course its aligned to 8 bytes*/
}
```

Is it possible to make an empty type, for example with just functions, take up no space in this way? I would have thought it'd be an easy optimization for the compiler to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since C++20, you can use the [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) attribute:

```
#include <iostream>

struct empty {};

struct foo {
    [[no_unique_address]] empty b;
    int a;
};

int main() {
    foo x;
    std::cout << &x.b << '\n' << &x.a << '\n'; // may print the same address
    std::cout << sizeof(int) << ' ' << sizeof(x) << '\n'; // may be equal
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Visual Studio 2019, but it's nice to know it's a feature, and will probably become more popular.

Comment: @Zebrafish Have you tried this? [How to enable c++20 in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965923/how-to-enable-c20-in-visual-studio-2019-16-3-preview-4).

Comment: @Zebrafish  (and François) - I just tried it in Visual Studio, which according to [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) should support it, but it says `Warning C4648 standard attribute 'no_unique_address' is ignored` even though I've enabled `/std:c++latest`. Oh well, MSVC will get there one day :-) Edit: Oh, I have MSVC version 16.8 and it's been added in 16.9 - Updating now and testing again soon.

Comment: @Zebrafish I just upgraded to 16.9.3 and now the warning went away - but it still didn't report the same address (or `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(x)`) :-(